# SharePoint Online Add-in: getJSON on .txt File in Content Folder Returns 404

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I'm using the below code in a SharePoint Online Add-in to import data from a text file to my HTML:

```
$.getJSON("../Content/timeszones.txt", function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        $('#timezone').append(`<option value=${item.UTCDSTOffset}>${item.TZ}</option>`);
    })
}, console.log("fail"));
```

I'm getting the error:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR)GET -
>   `https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/develop_apps/WorldClock/Content/timeszones.txt`

My configuration is as follows and I've verified the file is included in the feature:
[image: Configuration]
[image: Feature]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the location "../Content/timeszones.txt" in your JS code is not correct. You should check where your timezones.txt is deployed to according to the definition in the Elements.xml and change the url in the JavaScript code accordingly. I would recommend to use a server relative Url in the JS code.

Comment: You're correct: I identified a typo by looking at Elements.xml - thank you